# Setting output path of the projects in solution file with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have a solution file that contains tens of project files. And I need to set the 'Output path:' of the compiled results to different directory for all the projects in a solution file. Can I change the output path one time with the solution file to apply the change to the all the projects in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can edit the build path within each project file looking for `<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>`, maybe you can work with search&replace to do this easily... Just a suggestion, hope this will help.